# What should I do to fix a error - syntax error (missing operator) in query expression?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a new in MS Access and trying to create mouse down actions using VBA. I need to do a message box to show additional information by clicking left button on a list box and delete information from this list box by clicking right button.

I understand how this should work, but I have a runtime error:

> `'3075' syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ktbl='.`

```
Private Sub List2_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim arg As String
Dim Response As Integer

Const vbLeftButton = 1
Const vbRightButton = 2

If Button = 1 Then
    arg = "SELECT nmtbl, dsctbl FROM Table1 WHERE ktbl=" & Me.List2.Column(1) & ";"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(arg)
    Response = MsgBox("Name: " & rs!nmtbl & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Do you need description?", vbYesNo, "INFO")
    If Response = vbYes Then MsgBox rs!dsctbl, , "Additional info ''" & rs!nmtbl & "''"
        rs.Close
ElseIf Button = 2 Then
    Response = MsgBox("Do you want to delete information?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Delete confirmation")
    If Response = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE cd1=" & Me.List2 & ";"
        MsgBox "Completed", vbInformation, "Message"
        Me.List2.Requery
    Else
        MsgBox "Canceled!", vbInformation, "Message"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I cannot find a mistake, what should I change in the code?

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Perhaps, you need `ktbl= '" & Me.List2.Column(1) & "' ;"`

Comment: @shahkalpesh, I tried to do as you said, but I recieved a run-time error '3464' data type mismatch.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the line beginning arg = "SELECT... and examine the value of arg. Paste the value of arg into a new query in the database and try to run it. You should get the same error but perhaps the error description will be more helpful.

Comment: @NicholasHunter, I ran a query, but I got an error data type mismatch in criteria expression, that's all.

Comment: You declare and set variable rs but use rst - why? What data type are ktbl and cd1? Edit question to show sample data as a text table. Step debug - do inputs show the expected data? MouseDown might not be appropriate event. Why bother with popup asking if user wants description? If you're going to make user respond to a popup, just give the description anyway.

Comment: Your error message doesn't show any parameter input. I suspect listbox does not have a value yet for the MouseDown event. Try MouseUp or AfterUpdate.

Comment: Can you give us examples of what data is in ktbl, and what values are in List2?  Perhaps a `Debug.Print arg` before you try to Open the Recordset, would make it easier to debug?

Comment: @June7, I fixed rst to rs. ktbl and cd1 have numeric data type. Everything works except arg (the first query). I don't know why, but this query works wirhout if then else condition. I'm a new in access and I don't understand how should I show sample data as a text table.

Comment: @Chronocidal, ktbl is a key in Table1 for connection with another table, List2 has nm1, klch, dsc1 (where nm1 and dsc1 - text, klch - number). ktbl is needed to link with klch.

Comment: What do you mean query works without If Then Else - without the `If Button`? That is weird. Again, did you step debug? You could use a forum that facilitates attaching files and provide db for analysis. Review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow